# Textbook Problem does not seem to chose right ODE to model tank with water

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

The problem, taken from the Spanish version of Numerical Methods for Engineers by Chapra, states the following: A vertical cylindrical tank drops it's water level at the following rate

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = -k\sqrt{y}$$

where $t$ is time and $k$ is a constant that depends on the draining source; when $y(0) = 3$. Solving this ODE I get the following function (taking the positive root of $y$)

$$y = \bigg( \frac{2\sqrt{3} - kt}{2} \bigg)^2$$

This being a parabola, signifies that after a time $2\sqrt{3}/k$ the water level starts rising again. This last part is what I don't understand, since the problem never mentions water poured into the tank.

So basically the question is why the water level is rising again and what it means physically. Is the ODE wrong? Am i solving this the wrong way? Any light shed on this is highly appreciated

Comment: You have to understand that $y$ will be zero after all water comes out of the tank. This condition is not specified explicitly. Your solution is correct. $y=0$ also satisfies this ODE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subtlety here is that the solution $y(t) = \left( \frac{2\sqrt{3} - kt}{2} \right)^2$ is valid only for $t\le2\sqrt3/k$.

At $t=2\sqrt3/k$, the value of $y(t)$ as defined above is zero, and the differential equation asserts that $dy/dt$ will be zero at that moment -- which means $y$ must remain zero for all subsequent $t$. So the proper solution to the differential equation is:
$$
y(t)=\begin{cases}
\left( \frac{2\sqrt{3} - kt}{2} \right)^2&\text{if $t\le2\sqrt3/k$}\\
0&\text{if $t>2\sqrt3/k$}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Actually, $dy/dt$ being zero does not in general mean that $y$ has to remain zero; that only holds if you know that the ODE has a *unique* solution. But in this case, where $dy/dt \le 0$ and $y$ cannot be negative, it forces $y$ to stay at zero. But if you instead would consider this ODE with the time direction reversed, $dy/dt=+k \sqrt{y}$, then starting from $y=0$ the tank could spontaneously begin to fill up at any moment, so the solution isn't unique (and doesn't have to stay at zero).

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the ode is $kt + c =  -2y^{1/2}$, which is only possible for real numbers when $kt + c \leq 0$. When you square both sides, you create extra solutions that weren't there.